# Insert iterated values from one table to another in OracleDB

Tags: oracle, plsql, table

I'm pretty new in Oracle universe and I need help. I have to iterate through Users Table and insert these 3 specific rows into Task_Group Table. The hard thing to do is to check if these rows even exist (tables are just samples, I need to iterate through a table with a lot of rows), and then insert them only in rows and set Company_Number to: 22.[image]

Please help, guys!

Comment: so why only that three and nor the other?

Comment: @hotfix It's a task, I must iterate between 13256 row and 14639 row for example and insert them into a new table with Company_Number set to 22.

Comment: 13k rows is not a large amount of records, you can do it with an insert

Comment: @hotfix It's working on this template table, so thanks a lot, I will upvote and select your answer as my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the entry for the user already exists in the table and then exclude that users.

Depending on your data, you can do it with an insert, e.g.

```
insert into task_group (id, user_id, phone,name, company_no)
select rownum, id, phone,name, 22 
  from users u 
 where not exists(select 1 from task_group t where t.user_id = u.id);
```

you cann also loop over the data in your cursor and do commit every x Rows, but it is a very slow way to do that

Comment: Your first sentence : you would use a `MERGE` statement instead of `INSERT-SELECT`